# Allowing only my app to access a webpage

Tags: java, php, file, web

I have a file on a server
I have a java app which checks the file to get data
BUT I need to prevent any humans looking at the file

One obvious solution is to encrypt the file
But then by app would need the password, so my code would contain the password. And anyone who decompiles the code will have it

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could password protect the folder. Better, you could move the file to a location above public_html, where it can't be accessed with a web browser. Then your app would read it using ftp or whatever method you like.

But you'll always have the same problem. Anyone who guesses your password, or your ftp credentials, can read your file.

If you must store private data on a public network . . . well, we all do it, and the answer is to protect your domain with ssl.

Comment: See, the FTP wouldn't work because the credentials would have to be stored in the code. Which can be decompiled

Comment: So you can get an SSL certificate for the price of a couple of coffees (not including the cost of installing it, which varies). Some hosting companies include shared SSL for free.